# how to avoid Error: Can't set headers after they are sent?

Tags: node.js, express

I put my `res.send` in a loop and sometimes (too much often) i get the following error `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

Yet, i ensured that the `res.send` is  only fired after the last iteration.

```
 data.forEach( d => {
         i++
         new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
             //doing stuffs...then...
            resolve(result)

         }).then(value => {
           if(i === data.length){
               res.status(200).send(result) 
             }
            })

       })
```

So How is it possible that my server throws me that headers has already been sent.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Maybe you could post the whole function. This example doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: You can't send several response.